# one to many unidirectional doctrine persistance

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I am having some real problems with doctrines **unidirectional** persistence.

```
/** @Entity @Table(name="va_area")
 **/
class Area extends ReferenceData 
{
}

/** @Entity @Table(name="network")
 **/
class Network
{
    /**
    * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Area")
    * @JoinColumn(name="area_code", referencedColumnName="id")
    **/
    protected $area;
}
```

when I try to set the area value on network by using either a proxy or the loaded object. Doctrine attempts to insert a new row inside Area. This is utterly frustrating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was my fault. I was using a different Entity Manager to load my child records. Used the same entity and it resolved the issue.